# Perforce (p4v) - Simple create/push/merge branch for git developer

Tags: git, command-line, version-control, perforce

## Background

I come from a [git](/questions/tagged/git) background, and have been using it for years. Prior to that, I used [subversion](/questions/tagged/subversion) for several years, and had to occasionally use CVS.

## Question

I'm starting on a large perforce project and want to create a feature branch so that:

- I don't impact trunk/mainline/master.
- I can backup my work at end-of-day to the remote server.

With a tool like `git`, this was pretty easy:

```
git checkout -b my_branch
# make some edits
git add -u
git commit
git push
```

How do I accomplish the same (more or less) in perforce, **using the command-line interface**? Apparently I have to first use `p4 branch` to "create a branch spec", and then use `p4 integrate` to "open files for merging or branching", but couldn't find any concrete examples that make sense.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want something that's comparable to the git experience you probably want to be using Perforce's DVCS mode:  https://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.2/manuals/dvcs/

So, assuming you're doing this in your own local server, the flow is like this:

```
p4 fetch
p4 switch -c my_branch
# make some edits
p4 submit -d "Made my edits."
p4 switch main
p4 fetch
p4 merge --from my_branch
p4 resolve -am
p4 submit -d "Merged my edits into main."
p4 push
```

If you're doing this directly on a shared server that uses streams, you can skip the fetching and pushing part since every submit is already going straight to the "remote" (although I'll assume the allwrite/auto-reconcile feature that mimics "git commit -a" isn't on in that case, so you'll be using "p4 edit" to open your files for edit):

```
p4 switch -c my_branch
p4 edit (your files)
# make some edits
p4 submit -d "Made my edits."
p4 switch main
p4 merge --from my_branch
p4 resolve -am
p4 submit -d "Merged my edits into main."
```

If you're doing this on a shared server that doesn't use streams (i.e. "classic Perforce") then it's:

```
p4 integ //depot/main/... //depot/my_branch/...
cd my_branch
p4 submit -d "Created my branch."
p4 edit (your files)
# make some edits
p4 submit -d "Made my edits."
p4 integ //depot/my_branch/... //depot/main/...
p4 resolve -am
p4 submit -d "Merged my edits into main."
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to use DVCS and your site uses streams, have a look at Task Streams:
  https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/p4guide/chapter.streams.html#streams.types.task

You can use these to work on bug-fixes or features and they are semi-private.

Once you are happy with the work it can be merged back to the main stream/branch.

They even work with non-streams depots.b